# TypeScript hide protected class method in derived

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, inheritance, encapsulation

I have a class hierarchy like this:

```
abstract class Base {
  private b: string;
  abstract protected x() {}
  abstract pub(): void;
}

class D1 extends Base {
  private d: number;
  protected x() { ... }
  pub() {}
}
```

I need to expose a derived class to API consumers:

```
class D2 extends D1 {
}
```

... but I don't want users of `D2` to use protected/private members of its superclasses (accidentally or on purpose). But, `D2` must have access to public superclass members. Is it possible to hide the internals (via symbol or something else?) while still making `(new D2()) instanceof D1` checks pass? I can change any of the private/protected internals, but the public API needs to stay unchanged.

Comment: _"I don't want users of D2 to use protected/private members of its superclasses"_ ... that's exactly what protected/private are for. Did you mean you don't want D2 _itself_ to be able to use these?

Comment: Yes, I am forced to use the inheritance hierarchy but I don't want the users of D2 to trample on methods or redefine them.

Comment: That didn't really clarify things for me — what do you mean by "users of D2"? Do you mean people who write `class X extends D2` or people who write `new D2()`?

Comment: Users will write class `D2 extends D1 {}` (and many others extending `D1`). I want their derived classes to be `instanceof D1`, but not be able to clobber the protected members of D1 and Base. For example, `class X extends D1 { x() { return 5; } }` clobbers `D1.x` inside `X`

Comment: To add to this: I may not be able to ship typings with the code, so it would be JS. So they wouldn't have linter/inference to know they are clobbering `D1.x`

Comment: If clients are not using TS, there is probably not a lot you can do to prevent them from _maliciously_ poking at internals, except true [private members](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#ecmascript-private-fields) (`#foo`), although Symbols may help prevent _accidental_ clobbering (although in my experience are harder to use in TypeScript). Any `private`/`protected`/`public` annotations are erased when the code is compiled to JS.

Comment: It seems like `#foo` private members is a partial solution, but I don't know of any solution for `protected` members.

Comment: Would an Interface work to isolate the parts you need to cut access to?

Comment: If you are referring to a TS `interface`: I don't think so; it would hide `protected` member from the typings, but not prevent access/overwrite if the user defines their own that happens to have the same name.

Comment: One possible solution is to move the protected code to statics outside the class hierarchy, which is ugly and hard to maintain, but side-steps this issue.